# Belyi function : degree of pole is the degree of the face - why?

Tags: complex-analysis, riemann-surfaces

A Belyi function is a ramified cover $\beta : X \rightarrow \mathbb{P}^1\mathbb{C} $ unramified outside $\{ 0,1,\infty\}$.

Now if I colour the vertex 0 black, 1 white and look at the preimage $\beta^{-1}([0,1])$, I understand that we get a connected bipartite graph and the valency of the black and white vertices in the preimage are the multiplicities of the critical points, as on a neighbourhood of 0 and 1, $\beta$ looks like $z \mapsto z^k$.

What I fail to see however, is why the **degree of a pole is equal to the number of edges incident to a face**.

Can someone help me out with why this is? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Draw a triangle $T$ in the Riemann sphere, with vertices $0$, $1$ and $\infty$, and colour the edges red, blue and green say.
Now look at the inverse image $T'$ of $T$. This is a triangulation of $X$
and we colour its edges according to their image in $T$. Let the $0$-$1$
edge be red. At a pole of $\beta$, $k$ blue and $k$ green edges emerge,
where $k$ is the order of the pole. So $2k$ triangles of $T$ meet at that
point, and they combine to form a face of $\beta^{-1}(T)$
with $2k$ edges. (The faces of $\beta^{-1}(T)$ have an even number
of edges since it's a bipartite graph).

Comment: Sorry I still can't see what the order of the pole has to do with the number of edges emerging out of the point. Also, doesn't your argument show that the degree is half the number of edges incident to the face?